# objective c - Open with suggestions when trying to open URL schemes

Tags: ios, objective-c, deep-linking, url-scheme

I started an application that can handle SMS or Mail url schemes but I don't want to open the default apps installed. I have tried doing this

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL: url];
```

but this opens the default SMS and Mail apps.

I tried using the UIActivityViewController

```
NSString *url=@"mailto:sample@gmail.com";
NSURL *schemeURL = [NSURL URLWithString:url];
NSString * title =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Send Email",url];
NSArray* dataToShare = @[url];
UIActivityViewController* activityViewController =[[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:dataToShare applicationActivities:nil]
```

but this doesn't prefill the recipient field with the specified email.

It would be nice if the behaviour is the same with UIActivityViewController but let's us prefill information such as recipient.

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use non-default apps on macos but I don't think you can do so on iOS. Have a look at e.g. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplication/1648685-openurl?language=objc .

You could try with a URL similar to below to send with a given subject and body.

```
@"message://mailto://sample@gmail.com?subject=Subject&body=Body"
```

I think if you drop the `message` bit it will still work. I use it like that inside a HTML page inside an app somewhere.

If you need any special characters you will have to encode them in the subject and body.

Comment: This doesn't work with UIActivityViewController. The recipient will still be left out

Comment: Ok - that one works for me albeit in a different context. It should work though but exactly how I am not sure. Sometimes it seems you'd use it as ```mailto:sample@gmail.com``` as mentioned here https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/MailLinks/MailLinks.html Sometimes you'd encode the ```@``` and sometimes you'd pass the address as a parameter e.g. ```message?mail=omnifocusmadeeasy%40gmail.com``` which I got from https://thesweetsetup.com/working-email-urls-macos

Comment: It seems this is not possible doing in iOS as Apple drops the recipient and just put it plainly in the body. Seems to work in macOS but my target is iOS, sadly.